# SVG how to calculate feColorMatrix?

Tags: html, svg

How to calculate feColorMatrix?

I don't know why my calculation is incorrect.
I use  to add a filter to circle, then I try to calculate the final result.

Assuming 'red' is (255,0,0) when I use feColorMatrix

```
value="
 .5 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0"
to mult 
255   //red Matrix,it is rgba(255,0,0,0)
 0
 0
 0
```

The final result should be (127,0,0) but in I get (187,0,0)

This is how I calculate
[image: This is how I calculate]

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 150 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="colorMatrix">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
         .5 0 0 0 0
         0 1 0 0 0
         0 0 1 0 0
         0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
  <g filter="">
      <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"  /> //circle1
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#colorMatrix)">
      <circle cx="80" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"  /> //circle2
  </g>
</svg>
```

[circle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9Tu.png)

Answer (score 2):

By default [most filters use the linearRGB colour space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation-filters). You've forgotten to do that conversion or don't want it. You can tell the filter to run in the sRGB colour space and then you get the output you expect.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 150 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="colorMatrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
         .5 0 0 0 0
         0 1 0 0 0
         0 0 1 0 0
         0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
  <g filter="">
      <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"  /> //circle1
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#colorMatrix)">
      <circle cx="80" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"  /> //circle2
  </g>
</svg>
```